# Ensuring positive definite matrix defined by variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working with a piece of Matlab where I have:

```
n = 4;
Mbar = zeros(n,n);
Mbar(1,1) = M;
Mbar(2,2) = Ixx;
Mbar(3,3) = Iyy;
Mbar(4,4) = Izz;

L = zeros(n,n);
L = chol(Mbar)';
```

An error message said that it didn't like `M`, `Ixx`, `Iyy`, and `Izz`. So I changed the code to:

```
syms M Ixx Iyy Izz;
assume(M>0);
assume(Ixx>0);
assume(Iyy>0);
assume(Izz>0);
M = vpa(Mbar(1,1));
Ixx = vpa(Mbar(2,2));
Iyy = vpa(Mbar(3,3));
Izz = vpa(Mbar(4,4));

L = zeros(n,n);
L = chol(Mbar)';
```

An error message was returned stating that `Mbar` must be positive definite for the Cholesky decomposition to be performed. Is there a way to define the variables in `Mbar` such that I am ensured that `Mbar` is positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really have no idea what you are trying to do. All of your code is out of order. I think that this is all that you need, though the result is trivial for a diagonal matrix:

```
syms M Ixx Iyy Izz;
assume(M>0);
assume(Ixx>0);
assume(Iyy>0);
assume(Izz>0);
Mbar = diag([M Ixx Iyy Izz]);
L = chol(Mbar)'
```

which returns

```
L =

[ M^(1/2),         0,         0,         0]
[       0, Ixx^(1/2),         0,         0]
[       0,         0, Iyy^(1/2),         0]
[       0,         0,         0, Izz^(1/2)]
```

The reason the first case didn't work is because you were using Matlab's default numeric functionality and had not assigned any values to `M`, `Ixx`, etc. You got the error in the second case because you didn't create your `Mbar` matrix other than allocate it as all zeros.

Comment: ~ I will try this.  I have no values for M, Ixx, etc.  I needed to find L based on Mbar to be used in another piece of code that generates random matrices such that, ultimately, Mr = L*G*L'.  Thanks!!

Comment: ~ this error message showed up:  Undefined function 'chol' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

L = chol(Mbar)';

Comment: What version of Matlab do you have? What does `which sym/chol` return? Do you get a help result for `help sym/chol`?

Comment: ~ figured it out.  I did need concrete numbers to use in Matlab.  It did not like the symbols.  I think I'm using 2010b.  It may be newer though.  The university gives us copies.  At any rate, I used your simplified version with some actual values for the x, y, and z positions of my cuboid.  Thanks!!